# Can {2,3,4,5,.........,n,1} be called worst case of bubble sort?

Tags: sorting, big-o, complexity-theory, bubble-sort

Its mentioned at many places that bubble sort's worst case happens when we have sorted array in reverse order. But we can get $\Theta(n^2)$ complexity in other case also.

I have wrote the following code for bubble sort (C):

```cpp
void bubbleSort(int * arr, int size)
{
    for ( int i = size; i > 1; i-- ) // i is size of Unsorted array
    {
        bool swapped = false;
        for ( int j = 0 ; j <= i-2; j++ )
        {
            if ( arr[j] > arr[j+1] )
            {
                swap(arr+j, arr+j+1);
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
        if ( swapped == false )
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now for worst case, I was thinking that we should never encounter the break. That means we should at least have one swap in each pass. So now I started constructing an example array starting from size = 2. So one of the arrays satisfying the condition is `{2,3,4,5,1}`.

For any such array I am getting $\Theta(n^2)$ complexity, which is same as the worst case complexity described elsewhere.

But is this array the most worst case? In the case of descending ordered array, we have one swap for each comparison, but in my example we have a single swap in each pass. So the actual run time would be lower in my example (same number of comparisons in both examples though).

I get that big theta is just an approximation, but is the "worst case" described with respect to asymptotic approximation or actual run time?

Edit: In the book: "Data Structures with C (Schaum's Outline Series)"
on page 2.15 its written:

> The time is measured by counting the number of key operations - in sorting and searching algorithms, the number of comparisons.

Both the examples above have same number of comparisons, so should they both be worst cases?

Answer (score 0):

What a worst-case input is depends highly on the context you are looking at.

As you correctly noticed, your example and the reverse ordered list have the same asymptotic complexity of `θ(n^2)`. If you are only interested in asymptotic runtimes, both examples are fine.

If you look at the exact number of operations the reverse order is worse, since it does also `θ(n^2)` swaps compared to only `θ(n)` swaps in your example.

However, the biggest absolute number of operations does not necessarily result in the worst running time. E.g. would a list with the smallest element at the end and the other elements in random order probably have a worse runtime than the list in reverse order since on most systems the branch predictor would fail half of the time, depending on the level of compiler optimizations.